# jquery validation using match function

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to ensure a html field contains at least 7 integers for a form validation on a contact-us page using jquery.

I want to integrate this into JQuery's validation function doing something [similar to this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/minlength).

My question is - how do I integrate the new function into JQuery's validation?

Comment: And what have you tried?  Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@elclanrs - you got me most of the way.

This is what I ended up going with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    success: "valid"
  });;

  jQuery.validator.addMethod('sevenDigitsOrMore', function( value ) {
      return value.replace(/[^0-9]/gi,"").length >= 7 ;
  }, 'Enter at least 7 digits');
</script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
      rules: {
        field: {
          sevenDigitsOrMore: true
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.validator.addMethod('sevenDigitsOrMore', function( value ) {
  return /^\d{7,}$/.test( value );
}, 'Enter at least 7 digits');
```

Comment: Ok - so to use it - would I do:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      sevenDigitsOrMore: true
    }
  }
});

???